# Ubuntu 22.04 server not booting

Tags: boot

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 server hosted by OVH. It is configured with 3 drives soft RAID. Yesterday, two of the drives failed and were replaced. Using OVH's rescue system, I have used fdisk to copy the partition setup from the working drive (sdb) to the two new drives (sda and sdc). I have then used mdadm to put them into RAID arrays and waited for them to replicate so that all three drives now have identical content. However, if I attempt to boot from disk, the system fails to come up. Any ideas? Have I missed a step?

I have a full backup so I can reinstall from scratch if necessary, but I would like to avoid that if possible.